# Conjugate elements of $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: group-theory, matrices

Decide whether or not the two matrices $A= \begin{pmatrix} 3 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$ and $B= \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ -2 & 4 \end{pmatrix}$ are conjugate elements of the general linear group $GL_2(\mathbb{R})$

So I need to show that there exists a matrix $X= \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{pmatrix} \in GL_2(\mathbb{R})$ such that $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}$ and such that $ad-bc \neq 0$

I solved the system $XAX^{-1}=B$ and found that the the matrix is of the form $X= \begin{pmatrix} a & 0 \\ b & 0 \end{pmatrix}$ which is not invertible hence A and B are not conjugate elements.

Is it correct?  Is there an easier way to solve this type of question ?

Comment: Have you ever taken a course in Linear Algebra? If so, consider the following hint. $$\text{Hint: what is the purpose of similar matrices?}$$

Comment: Diagonalize the matrix $B$ and you find that's similar to $A$.

Comment: Group theory before basic linear algebra? Weird.

Answer (score 4):

It can readily be seen that $2$ is an eigenvalue of $B$ because the sum of each row is always $2$. Since the trace of $B$ is $5$ it follows that $3$ is also an eigenvalue of $B$, therefore $B$ is [diagonalizable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonalizable_matrix) and [similar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Similar_(linear_algebra)) to $A$, that is, there exists $X$ such that $X^{-1}BX=A$.

So you have made a miscalculation in solving the system. If you want to solve a system I suggest solving the equivalent, and in my opinion easier system:$XA=BX$.

**Edit:** Diagonalizability is a field-dependent concept. All that was said above is with respect to $\Bbb R$. It maybe the case that a real matrix isn't diagonalizable in $\Bbb R$ and it is $\Bbb C$.

Comment: Do you perhaps mean $XA=BX$?...

Comment: @user1729Yes, thanks. I had even thought of that and ended up writing the wrong thing for some reason.

Comment: @GitGud Could you include perhaps what are the various ways of showing that two matrices are similar ? Because I know how to show that they are not

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol Oh, man. There's so much stuff on that related to [SNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form), [JNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form), [invariant factors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariant_factor), etc. There's no easy, universal shortcut. However, if you're lucky enough that the matrices are diagonalizable, it's very easy to check.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol If you want a fast, universal, way to deal with this, I suggest you learn about JNF. JNF states that every matrix is similar to a "unique" certain kind of matrix $J$ and since matrix similarity is a transitive relation, you just need to find $J$ for each of your matrices to conclude if they are similar or not. There's a lot of theory leading up to JNF, but the algorithm to finding $J$ isn't that hard, you can do it without understanding it. However this is not the place to describe it, that merits a new question. Although such a question might not be welcomed.

Comment: Such a question probably exists already! (Although I will not try to find it...)

Comment: @user1729 I agree, but it's outside of the scope of the site to explain how to perform an algorithm, I believe.

Comment: @Jean-FrancoisRossignol Anyway, there are probably dozens of questions asking to find the JNF of specific matrices, maybe you can learn by example.

Answer (score 2):

$XA=BX$ is equivalent to $c=2a$ and $d=b$, i.e.,
$$
X=\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\
2a & b
\end{pmatrix}
$$
We need $0\neq \det(X)=-ab$, which is possible with, say, $a=b=1$.

Remark: It is easy to see that $A$ and $B$ have the same characteristic polynomial, since they have the same trace and the same determinant. For $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ this is not enough to conclude that they are similar.

Answer (score 1):

Because the trace and the determinant coincide, so does the characteristic polynomial, in particular its roots=eigenvalues. Both eigenvalues are distinct, so both matrices similar to a diagonal matrices with entries $2$ and $3$.

Comment: No, distinct eigenvalue must have algebraic multiplicity = geometric multiplicity, because the sum of all algebraic multiplicities is equal two and each alg. multiplicity at least one.